# Components of independent vectors

Tags: probability

Suppose $(X_1,X_2)$ is independent of $(Y_1,Y_2)$. Does it follow that $X_1$ is independent of $Y_1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Let $(X_1,X_2)$ be independent of $(Y_1,Y_2)$ and $f,g: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ measurable functions. Then $f(X_1,X_2)$ and $g(Y_1,Y_2)$ are independent. Choose suitable functions $f,g$ to conclude that $X_1$ and $Y_1$ are independent.